# css list selector in jQuery, inherit bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, inheritance

I have page like this:

```
<ul id="cards">
  <li id="card1">
    <div>...</div>
    <div id="panel1">
      <form>...</form>
      <ol class="commentlist" id="commentlist1">
        <li>...</li>
        ...
      </ol>
    </div>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Basically, there is a list of cards, each card has a list of comments. The content of div with id "panelX" is generated by JQuery upon clicking a button (all comments and a form are not shown before clicking the button).

I define the CSS of `#cards` and `#cards li` in a css file, and `ol.commentlist` in jQuery.

`$('ol.commentlist').css()` seems to work but `$('ol.commentlist li').css()` doesn't, as it is still inherited from `#cards li`.

Also, `$('ol#commentlistX').css()` works but `$('ol#commentlistX li').css()` doesn't.

+++++++

**Update:**

I found BenM's solution only avoids inheriting from the `$(#card li)`, but `$('ol.commentlist li').css()` still doesn't work.

++++++

**Update:**

I figured out. Because `<li>` within `<ol>` is generated by AJAX, and by the time I set css, it is not generated yet. I moved the css setting in AJAX and it works.

And I understand what Leo means "inline style".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your CSS rule for the `li`:

```
ul#cards > li {  }
```

This will ensure that the style is only applied to **direct child** elements of `ul#cards`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's .css() method apply inline styles to your elements, so it should overwrite other styles even if `#cards li` is a stronger selector than `ol.commentlist li`.

Have you tried to log the result of your selector to make sure you are actually catching some dom elements?

Comment: I added `alert($('ol#commentlist' + id + ' li').css())`, and it said undefined.